# check if it's a magic square with python

Tags: python

Input consists of several cases, each with the order n of a square, followed by n rows, each with n natural numbers between 1 and n².
Like:

```
3
6 1 8
7 5 3
2 9 4

1
1
(...)
```

extra conditions:

- all the numbers between 1 and n² appear once
- All rows, columns and the two major diagonals must sum the same.

should print ("yes") if its a magic square and ("no") if don't

so my code solves all correct inputs except the ones that have some number repeated, and I don't know how to solve that problem

my code

```
a = read(int)
while a is not None:
    check1 = True
    t = 0 
    s = 0
    listaA = [] 
    ## create matrix of lists like A([b[],b[],b[]])
    for j in range(a):
        b = []
        for k in range(a):
            c = read(int)
            if c in listaB:
                (a-1) - k
            listaB.append(c)
            b.append(c)
        listaA.append(b)
    if a == 1:
        check1 = False
        print("yes")
    else:
        x = sum(listaA[0])
    i=0
    while i<a and check1 == True:
    #for i in range(a):
        # suma la primera fila 
        suma=sum(listaA[i])
        if x != suma:
            print('no')
            break
        ## check columns 
        y = 0
        for j in range(a):
            y += listaA[j][i]
        if y != x:
            print('no')
            break
        i+=1
    ## check diagonals
    if i==a: 
        for i in range(a):
            t += (listaA[i][i])
            s += listaA[i][(a-1)-i]
        if s != x or t != x:
            print('no')

        else:
            print('yes')
    a = read(int)
```

some idea ???

Comment: Could you be more specific in the problem? For instance, some example in/output would be nice.

Comment: Split your code up into more understandable chunks and test each function you write. In it's current state it's hard to tell where the error might be. Separate reading in data, printing out results, and the process of checking an array's 'magic'ness.  Try writing a rowSum function and a function to check whether all the rowSums are the same. Test everything.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a set comparison to check if all the numbers between 1 and n² appear once, and use `sum` with generator expressions like this to test if all rows, columns and the two major diagonals sum the same:

```
def is_magic(m):
    n = len(m)
    s = (n ** 2 + 1) * n // 2
    return (
        set(range(1, n ** 2 + 1)) == set(i for r in m for i in r) and
        all(sum(r) == s for r in (*m, *zip(*m))) and
        sum(m[i][i] for i in range(n)) == sum(m[i][-i - 1] for i in range(n)) == s
    )
```

so that:

```
is_magic(
    [
        [6, 1, 8],
        [7, 5, 3],
        [2, 9, 4]
    ]
)
```

returns:

```
True
```